# Why Laravel showing custom word in my body tag?

Tags: laravel

Recently, I noticed that `artisan` command throwing some word after `config:cache` command and now this word appears in my body tag and broke my entire HTML code(things from head tag appear in body tag).

```
> php artisan config:cache
Configuration cache cleared!
imgConfiguration cached successfully!
```

I tried to delete all html code from my `app.blade.php` (my main blade file)
But anyway, nothings shows but this word **img**

Any help, thank u.

Comment: Does any of your service providers have `dump('word')` in it?

Comment: You might have that word in another file, possibly at the very beginning. Try this from the command line: `grep -R 'img' * | egrep -v 'resources|storage'`. This may take awhile, but hopefully it will help you narrow down where it might be.

Comment: Should I check all my providers for this word?

Comment: Can you run following in terminal from the laravel's project root `grep -ril 'img' app`?

Comment: Damn, it was stupid error. In one of my providers I accidently put this word at the beggining. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in one provider. I put accidently this word at the begging of the file